# Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong with the loops in my program?

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I am new to C and was making a program where a hash grid is drawn and the user inputs the dimensions of a grid. I also used the cs50 Library to get a int. When ever I input the dimensions, no hashes show up. Please help me. Thanks in advance
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void){
    int x;
    int y;
    do{
        x=get_int("Width of the hash floor: ");
        y=get_int("Length of the hash floor: ");
        return x;
        return y;
    } while (x>1);
    for (int n=0;n<x;n++){
        printf("#");
        for(int a=0;a<y;a++){
            printf("#\n");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` statements end/exit the function immediately.

Comment: `return` means exit the current function.

Comment: @Lucas the `return 0?  from `main` is not necessary. `main` implicitly returns 0.

Comment: @Lucas so did I, and I will remove this one too. You can rem ove your last comment too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

- remove both `return` statements, they don't make any sense here.
- change the while loop (see comment in the code below).

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int y;

    do{
        x = get_int("Width of the hash floor: ");
        y = get_int("Length of the hash floor: ");
    } while (x < 1 || y < 1);  // ask for width and length until both
                               // x and y are larger than 0

    for (int n = 0; n < x; n++) {
        printf("#");
        for (int a = 0; a < y; a++) {
            printf("#\n");
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in the do while ...
Don't use return and let the condition of while fulfill.
The Return instruction is used to return to the Main Program from a Subroutine Program or Interrupt Program